# Stuck on the SOL moon in MirrorMoon EP

Tags: mirrormoon-ep

I enjoyed the first level of [MirrorMoon EP](http://store.steampowered.com/app/231310/), looks like a cool game so far. But I'm completely lost on what to do on SOL.

Moon Screenshot:

[image: SOL moon, too bright to see much without an eclipse]

Navigation Menu Screenshot:

[image: the star system with SOL]

Coordinates:

```
455588495
454488495
0000.0 PC
T 0000:00
V........
T 0000:00
90F57BF5DF
```

On side A, the disk says 95%, and doesn't let me play. On side B, the disk now says 94%. Does that mean I've already done everything I can possibly do?

1. I start by rushing towards the concentric circles to an elephant boneyard-looking flashing house. A click sound happens when I arrive, but nothing seems to change other than the rings stop ringing.
2. I go to the tent and pick up the red triangular pyramid moon-rotator.
3. I go to the archway that illuminates when the animated markers hit it, and pick up the blue moon-marker shooter.

Then I go to the broken tower and watch an eclipse every five minutes or so. The only change seems to be the sky darkening, and the navigator cursor reappearing on the moon.

I have no idea what to do after that. I tried:

- Walking into the tiny white ball at one tower (takes me back to the navigation menu)
- Searching for the moon-dragger gun piece (can't find it)
- Rotating the moon every which way (no change)
- Shooting sites like on the intro level (no change)
- Standing at the broken tower during an eclipse (navigation cursor reappears, much wow)
- Standing near the rocks pointed at by the middle row of running markers

The left and right rows of running markers point at two pieces of the gun. The middle row seems to point at an empty patch of land, with two rocks and not much else.

**Would someone be kind enough to try this game and give me a hint or two for SOL?**

MirrorMoon looks like an awesome game, but I can't help feeling a little frustrated my first moon after the intro level. Ordinarily, I'd go to IGN walkthroughs or the MirrorMoon wiki, but both are almost resources completely empty.

Also posted on [r/walkthrough](http://www.reddit.com/r/walkthrough/comments/1sww39/request_mirrormoon_ep_walkthrough_for_the_sol/). The video game has such a small following that I haven't gotten much feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You arrived at a planet which was solved by another player and named SOL. Travel to planets with a name like XYZ/12 as they have not been discovered. You are probably in an early season, so start a new game on the current season.